# Combining all rows with the same value in "name" column into one row

Tags: sql

I've taken details of a large number of deals from monthly data sets, some of which are in every data set and some which are not, and combined them into one data set called 'Month by Month Data Set'. I want to store their "Stage" value in each month under a new column (e.g. stage February) and, if there is no value for that month, set it as N/A.

The key issue I'm having is that I don't know how to combine all the deals with the same name into one column, so my current code has a row each time a deal shows up and every column, except the one from the current month, says N/A which doesn't really help me.

I'm new to SQL so I'm sure I'm missing something simple

```
SELECT
         "Deal Name",
         if("month"  = 'February', "Stage", 'None') AS "Stage February",
         if("month"  = 'March', "Stage", 'None') AS "Stage March",
         if("month"  = 'April', "Stage", 'None') AS "Stage April",
         if("month"  = 'May', "Stage", 'None') AS "Stage May",
         if("month"  = 'June', "Stage", 'None') AS "Stage June",
         if("month"  = 'July', "Stage", 'None') AS "Stage July"
FROM  "Month by Month Stage Data"
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @JoeCampbell . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT "Deal Name",
        max(case when "month"  = 'February' then "Stage" end) AS "Stage February",
        max(case when "month"  = 'March' then "Stage" end) AS "Stage March",
        max(case when "month"  = 'April' then "Stage" end) AS "Stage April",
        max(case when "month"  = 'May' then "Stage" end) AS "Stage May",
        max(case when "month"  = 'June' then "Stage" end) AS "Stage June",
        max(case when "month"  = 'July' then "Stage" end) AS "Stage July"
FROM "Month by Month Stage Data"
GROUP BY "Deal Name";
```

The above returns `NULL` instead of `'None'`.  If you really want `'None'`, use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT "Deal Name",
        coalesce(max(case when "month"  = 'February' then "Stage" end), 'None') AS "Stage February",
        coalesce(max(case when "month"  = 'March' then "Stage" end), 'None') AS "Stage March",
        coalesce(max(case when "month"  = 'April' then "Stage" end), 'None') AS "Stage April",
        coalesce(max(case when "month"  = 'May' then "Stage" end), 'None') AS "Stage May",
        coalesce(max(case when "month"  = 'June' then "Stage" end), 'None') AS "Stage June",
        coalesce(max(case when "month"  = 'July' then "Stage" end), 'None') AS "Stage July"
FROM "Month by Month Stage Data"
GROUP BY "Deal Name";
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect